# WebGL Position vertex inside vertex shader?

Tags: javascript, position, webgl, vertex-shader, vertex

My goal is to specify custom positions for vertices within the shader vertex rather than relying on a JavaScript "new Float32Array(positions)" for defining vertex positions. The data should represent a simple triangle shape. Additionally, I aim to ensure that the vertices are positioned precisely as intended to achieve the desired visual outcome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>WebGL Example</title>
    <style>
        canvas {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            var gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');

            const shaderSource = {
                vertex: `
                 
                          uniform vec2 screenSize; // Screen size uniform

                          void main(void) {
                              // Define combined vertices
                              vec3 vertices[3];
                              vertices[0] = vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
                              vertices[1] = vec3(-1.0, -1.0, 0.0);
                              vertices[2] = vec3(1.0, -1.0, 0.0);

                              // Adjust vertices based on screen size
                              for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                                  vertices[i].x *= screenSize.x / screenSize.y; // Adjust x coordinate based on aspect ratio
                              }

                              // Create another vec3 to store the vertices
                              vec3 finalPosition = vec3(0.0);

                              // Add the selected vertex to finalPosition
                              finalPosition vec3(vertices[0],vertices[1],vertices[2]);

                              // Calculate final position
                              gl_Position = vec4(finalPosition, 1.0);
                          }


                `,
                fragment: `
                    void main(void) {
                        gl_FragColor = vec4(0, 0.8, 0, 1);
                    }
                `
            };

            var vertShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
            gl.shaderSource(vertShader, shaderSource.vertex);
            gl.compileShader(vertShader);

            var fragShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
            gl.shaderSource(fragShader, shaderSource.fragment);
            gl.compileShader(fragShader);

            var shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
            gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertShader);
            gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragShader);
            gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);
            gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

            // Clear the canvas
            gl.clearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
            gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            // Draw the triangle
            gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: found something similar to what I'm looking for https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-drawing-without-data.html

Comment: What is the end goal here? Because hard coding vertices like this, you'll just end up with a vertex shader only capable of drawing that specific triangle. So if you want to draw a different triangle or maybe even a quad, then it requires a completely separate vertex shader then. All in all, this is very unidiomatic to do in WebGL. But yes, you can calculate vertices positions anyway you'd like in the vertex shader. So what is the actual issue?

Comment: the issue is i can't draw no shapes inside the gl_Position with custom data inside the vectors shader. the reason why i want to achieve this because i have another program that creates Perlin noise data inside the shader due to better performance compared to js code. i have build a voxel game working up and running with perlin noise with controls but its slow for my liking.

Comment: Heres my old prototype of the code https://raw.githack.com/alex02NM/voxelds/main/index.html

Comment: If you already have the perlin noise in a shader, then you might be able to use a compute shader to both calculate the perlin noise and generate vertices. However, this really isn't easy to do (assuming you're new to WebGL). Honestly, it would be easier to rewrite this in a language that supports multithreading

Comment: yes, new to webgl but not new to programming and yes i agree multithreading a good option but my goal it not to build it in other languages like c++ , i have other algorithms that can render huge number of voxels for example I have a greed mesh algorithm and face culling , and other algorithms too but the problem is the Perlin noise algorithm is js is quite slow compared to shader Perlin noise with is possibly 100 or thousands times faster but i can't get the "gl_Position = vec4(finalPosition, 1.0);" code working i want a simple data of vectors in shaders not in js. sorry for bad english

Comment: also, heres some basic perlin noise algoirthms in webgl shaders "https://thebookofshaders.com/11/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is to use the gl_VertexID which creates a virtual point based on the numverts you want to set. the gl_VertexID will start from 0 - numverts and will require some math formula to calculate the shape you desire.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>WebGL Triangle</title>
  <canvas id="c"></canvas>
  <script src="https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-utils.js"></script>
  <script>
    // WebGL2 - No Data - Point Circle
// from https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/webgl-no-data-point-circle.html


'use strict';
const gl = document.querySelector('#c').getContext('webgl2');

const vs = `#version 300 es
uniform int numVerts;
uniform vec2 resolution;

#define PI radians(180.0)

void main() {
float u = float(gl_VertexID) / float(numVerts);  // goes from 0 to 1

// Define the vertices of the triangle
vec2 vertex1 = vec2(0.0, 0.0);  // Define the coordinates of the first vertex
vec2 vertex2 = vec2(0.0, 2.0);  // Define the coordinates of the second vertex
vec2 vertex3 = vec2(1.0, -0.7);  // Define the coordinates of the third vertex

// Interpolate between the vertices to get the position of the current point
vec2 pos = mix(mix(vertex1, vertex2, u), vertex3, u);

  //float angle = u * PI * 2.0;                      // goes from 0 to 2PI
  //float radius = 0.2;
  //vec2 pos = vec2(cos(angle), sin(angle)) * radius;




  gl_Position = vec4(pos, 0, 1);
  gl_PointSize = 10.0;
}
`;

const fs = `#version 300 es
precision highp float;

out vec4 outColor;

void main() {
  outColor = vec4(0, 0, 1, 1);
}
`;

// setup GLSL program
const program = webglUtils.createProgramFromSources(gl, [vs, fs]);
const numVertsLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'numVerts');
const resolutionLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'resolution');

const numVerts = 3;

// draw
webglUtils.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

gl.useProgram(program);

// tell the shader the number of verts
gl.uniform1i(numVertsLoc, numVerts);
// tell the shader the resolution
gl.uniform2f(resolutionLoc, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

const offset = 0;
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, offset, numVerts);

  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="webgl-utils.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```